# Object not clamping after applying force/impulse?

Tags: unity, c#

I am having issue with clamping the vertical position of my character after applying force. This causes a jittery effect in my character.

There are other several ways I think of, but I dont know if its the right way.

1. Use translate, but ive read somewhere that if I am dealing with physics its better that to use addforce.
2. Add an invisible gameobject with a collider to set bounderies.

and third is clamp its movement while using addforce which in my case does not work. here is my code which I call on the update.

```
 rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
 Vector3 clampedPOS = player.transform.position;

    clampedPOS.y = Mathf.Clamp(player.transform.position.y, -6f, 4f);
    player.transform.position = clampedPOS;


    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * upForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

could someone help me with these?

Comment: You said clamping the movement is "not working", is it throwing any errors? Or is it just causing the jittering? 

Have you tried calling the clamping in fixedUpdate rather than update? Jittering can frequently be caused by small timing differences between update and fixedUpdate.

Comment: it's not throwing any errors, instead the clamping happens only after I tap, but not after I apply the force. I Tried to use the tap/clamp function in fixedUpdate and it seems to be not responsive or am I doing it wrong? I cant seem to get how do I get the method to run in fixedupdate when I am calling it from update.

Comment: You mentioned that the clamping is only happening after you tap but you haven't included any code or explanation of how your game handles inputs so I think you need to include more context to get this question answered. With regards to update/fixedupdate, every monobehavior object has both an Update() and FixedUpdate() loop. Try moving the code out of Update and instead call it in FixedUpdate eg: `FixedUpdate(){ doStuff(); }`